# How can I access the IBoutlet on UIViewController from another class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I put UIButton on UIVIewController by StoryBoard.

in xxxVIewController.h

```
@interface xxxViewController : UIViewController{

IBOutlet UIButton *But;
}
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *But;
```

I would like to access "*But" from another class to change setimage of UIButton.

I think if I can get the instance of UIViewController,it is solved.....

Does anyone give me the hint

---

thanks He-Was ,Jasper Blues I added comments .

One is xxxViewController which doesn't contain navigation controller.
it contains only four buttons.

The other is TimerClass (NSObject)
which manage the time of application.

TimerClass class has timer.
What I want to do is 
changing the button color  on xxxViewController every a few seconds from TimerClass.

I can access TimerClass method easily.
because xxxViewController has TimerClass instance.

But xxxViewController was made by automatic,so I am not sure how to get xxxViewController instance from TimerClass.

Comment: what is the relationship between the two classes? (for example, are they both viewControllers contained in a navigation controller? or does one of the classes create and own the other? Please elaborate)

Comment: @user1942868: It's better to add specific details in the proper comments section, like this. . . Now, what to you mean by "made by automatic" ?

Comment: 'made by automatic' means xxxViewController is made by storyboard.
However I have to make timerclass in code such as
    (TimerClass *)TC = [TimerClass alloc];

Comment: @user1942868, check out Inafziger's answer -it's better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would setup `xxxVIewController` as a delegate for `TimerClass` and when you create your `TimerClass` instance, set the delegate to `self`.

ie:

```
self.timer = [[TimerClass alloc] init];
self.timer.delegate = self;  // This assumes that you have already created a declared property called delegate in your `TimerClass` class
```

Then, when it is time to update the button, you should call a delegate function in `xxxVIewController` and have it update its own button:

```
// Or whatever method that you want called
if (self.delegate respondsToSelector(@selector(changeButtonColor)))
{
    [self.delegate changeButtonColor];
}
```

Read up on protocols if you aren't familiar and you will see a good way to implement this in a more general fashion.

Comment: +1 for showing user1942868 how to do it properly right from the start. . . that's what I should've done in retrospect.

Comment: thanks Inafziger ! 
I finally make it .
"delegate" is the best way for my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, having declared the property, you need a pointer to the xxxViewController, from the class that will be doing the update.

If its in a UINavigationController you could access it from there. Otherwise (I'm trying to keep this simple in case you're just starting out) you could put it on eg the AppDelegate.